# keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "surahs", intValue: nil) json from URL

Tags: ios, swift

```
struct Results: Codable {
let code: Int
let status: String
let data: DataClass
}
struct DataClass: Codable {
let surahs: [Surah]
let edition: Edition
}

struct Edition: Codable {
let identifier, language, name, englishName: String
let format, type: String
}

struct Surah: Codable, Identifiable{
var id: String{
    return "\(number)"
}
let number: Int
let name, englishName, englishNameTranslation, revelationType: String
let ayahs: [Ayah]

}

struct Ayah: Codable, Identifiable{
var id: String{
    return "\(number)"
}
let number: Int
let audio: String
let audioSecondary: [String]
let text: String
let numberInSurah, juz, manzil, page: Int
let ruku, hizbQuarter: Int
let sajda: Bool
}
```

This is my Strucks

ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{

        List(networkManager.posts) {surah  in
            Text(surah.name)
        }
    .navigationBarTitle("Coran")
    }
    .onAppear {
        self.networkManager.fetchData()
    }
}
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
}
```

NetworkManager.swift

```
class NetworkManager : ObservableObject{

@Published var posts = [Surah]()

func fetchData() {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://api.alquran.cloud/v1/quran/ar.alafasy"){
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let safeData = data{
                    do{
                        let results = try decoder.decode(DataClass.self, from: safeData)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.posts = results.surahs
                        }

                    } catch{
                        print(error)
                    }

                }

            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
}
```

I try to call this URL in my Swift data but i get Error message , i need same help to finded the problem please.
this is the error message

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "surahs", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"surahs\", intValue: nil) (\"surahs\").", underlyingError: nil))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to decode a `DataClass` but the JSON from your URL looks like it's a `Results` object instead. Try decoding a `Results` object instead and see if that fixes your issue:

```
let results = try decoder.decode(Results.self, from: safeData)
```

Then, if you just want to get the `surahs` and store them into `self.posts`, you can say:

```
self.posts = results.data.surahs
```

However, you'll notice that if you just do the above, you'll still run into errors. Sometimes a `sajda` is a `Bool` and sometimes it's a `Dictionary`. So, you'll need to model a Sajda as its own struct and change the type of `Ayah.sajda` to be of that type instead of a `Bool`, and then handle the decoding appropriately:

```
struct Sajda: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let recommended: Bool
    let obligatory: Bool
}

struct Ayah: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String {
        return "\(number)"
    }

    let number: Int
    let audio: String
    let audioSecondary: [String]
    let text: String
    let numberInSurah: Int
    let juz: Int
    let manzil: Int
    let page: Int
    let ruku, hizbQuarter: Int
    let sajda: Sajda?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        number = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .number)
        audio = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .audio)
        audioSecondary = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .audioSecondary)
        text = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .text)
        numberInSurah = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .numberInSurah)
        juz = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .juz)
        manzil = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .manzil)
        page = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .page)
        ruku = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .ruku)
        hizbQuarter = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .hizbQuarter)

        sajda = try? container.decodeIfPresent(Sajda.self, forKey: .sajda)
    }
}
```

Notice that `sajda` is now an optional type – I assume that when the JSON returns that value as a `Bool` (which looks like it's only ever `false` and never `true`) that the backend developers really meant `null` for that object, so I've equated any `Bool` to mean `nil` for that object.